# Strange 'Dispose' Error when calling with 'Using' or directly calling 'DIspose'

Tags: vb.net

I have this code which works:

```
Option Strict On
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.ServiceModel
Imports System.ServiceModel.Description
...
 Private Property Channel As IWSOServiceContract

 Public Sub SomeMethod(ByVal url As String)
    Using ChlFactory As ChannelFactory(Of IWSOServiceContract) = New ChannelFactory(Of IWSOServiceContract)(New WebHttpBinding(), url)
       ChlFactory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(New WebHttpBehavior())
       Channel = ChlFactory.CreateChannel()
    End Using
 End Sub
...
```

But then when I refactor it to:

```
Option Strict On
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.ServiceModel
Imports System.ServiceModel.Description
...
Private Property ChlFactory As ChannelFactory(Of IWSOServiceContract)
Private Property Channel As IWSOServiceContract

Public Sub SomeMethod(ByVal url As String)
    ChlFactory = New ChannelFactory(Of IWSOServiceContract)(New WebHttpBinding(), url)
    ChlFactory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(New WebHttpBehavior())
    Channel = ChlFactory.CreateChannel()
    ChlFactory.Dispose()   '<-- ERROR HERE BUT HOW DID USING WORK BEFORE?
End Sub 
...
```

Am completely at a loss without any explanation of why there is an error "Dispose is not a member of ChannelFactory" in the second method but not in the first method?

Comment: Error 41 'Dispose' is not a member of 'System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory(Of IWSOServiceContract)'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because [`ChannelFactory` implements `IDisposable.Dispose` explicitly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb154894(v=vs.110).aspx). You'd have to cast it to `IDisposable` to call `Dispose`.

`Using` statement is smart enough to do the casting for you.

Comment: Interesting... never saw a case like this before. I guess that is why R# says: "Cannot access Private Dispose here" when I hover over it. So why does a private method all of a sudden become public if you cast to IDisposable?

Comment: That's how explicit interface implementation works. You implement interface member, but to access it caller has to treat you as that interface instance, not the concrete class. It's useful if you want to have another method with the same name and set of parameters and different type (e.g. `GetEnumerator` on `List<T>` is done this way, there are three of them, one for `IEnumerable`, another for `IEnumerable<T>` and yet another one which is not backed by any interface) or implement multiple interfaces with the same member, and you want to implement them differently.

Comment: Thank you. Very enlightening. Never saw this case before.